# Reflecting points in a bar graph using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

long time lurker for programming questions, first time poster.

I am writing some code where I am making a bar graph of a bunch of values, some of which are negative and some of which are positive- [plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VaimT.png)

In short, what I want to do is take all the negative values for the green part and overlay them onto the positive side, so you can see the asymmetry in those values.  I have tried a few methods to get this to work, and perhaps I'm not searching the correct things but can't seem to find a good answer on how to do this.

The relevant code I have so far (hopefully not leaving anything out that's important for the purposes of the plot...):

```
import glob
import pyrap.images as pim
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from scipy.optimize import * 

less_than_expected_min = -500
more_than_expected_max = 1200
n_bins = 100

bin_edges = np.linspace(less_than_expected_min, more_than_expected_max, n_bins)
for i in range(total):
    all_clipped_values = np.zeros([total,n_bins-1])

clipped_levels= np.sum(all_clipped_values,axis=0)

reflect= np.concatenate([clipped_levels[0:30], clipped_levels[30:0]])


plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1],clipped_levels,width=(more_than_expected_max -less_than_expected_min)/float(n_bins), log=True,color='green')
plt.bar(bin_edges[:-1],reflect,width=(more_than_expected_max -less_than_expected_min)/float(n_bins), log=True,color='red')
```

The issue when I try this method, however, is I get "AssertionError: incompatible sizes: argument 'height' must be length 99 or scalar."  It's not quite clear to me how to solve this, or in fact if there is a simpler way to do this reflection than what I'm thinking.

Any feedback appreciated- thanks!

Comment: In what line did you get this error?

Comment: I think in ``clipped_levels[30:0]`` you have to do a negative step size, like ``clipped_levels[30:0:-1]``

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is involved in your issue but I don't understand the `for i in range...` part : it assigns the same value to `all_clipped_values` at each iteration...

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, maybe this will clarify

```
>>> x = list(range(100))
>>> x[0:30]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
>>> x[30:0]
[]
>>> x[30:0:-1]
[30, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

You have to specify the negative step.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you call `plt.bar`, if your first argument is an array of length **n** (the set of abscissas), then your second argument must be an array of length **n** (the set of ordinates).

In your case, your set of abscissas is by construction an array of length 99, hence you must ensure your set of ordinates has the same shape.

For the first call, your second argument `clipped_levels` seems to have the right length, but for the second call, the second argument is `reflect` - which is far from 99 items long.

Fix that and it should work, hopefully !

**EDIT :**

Something like `reverse = np.concatenate([clipped_levels[:n_bins/2], clipped_levels[n_bins/2-2::-1]])` should do the trick.

Also, I still think your `for` loop could be replaced by a single instruction (the initialization of `all_clipped_values`), unless there is some other code inside that was not relevant here.

Comment: Ok, this helped- the line wasn't quite right because it mirrored the entire green section in the plot instead of just the negative parts, but toying around with it finally go the right answer.  Thanks!  I should also note yeah, there are other things going on in the for loop that I didn't put in as it wasn't relevant.